# Shutdown caused Tomcat 8.5 startup failure in NetBeans 19

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, tomcat8

Shutdown caused Tomcat 8.5 startup failure in NetBeans 19.

When my computer restarts (Windows 11), and I try to open NetBeans 19 and start Tomcat 8.5, it fails to start. I can only resolve it by redownloading NetBeans. (My JDK version is 17.) However, it's quite inconvenient to have to download it again every day. Is there any other solution? Can someone suggest an alternative approach to fix this issue?.

My Tomcat is giving an error message：*The system cannot find the specified file.*

Here is the Tomcat log:

[image: Log]

Comment: One possibility is that Tomcat is already running as a service before attempting to start it in NetBeans. But _"it fails to start"_ is too vague; without a more detailed and specific description of your problem the question cannot be answered. Update it to show the relevant content of the Tomcat log (which may include a stack trace), and any error message that is displayed when Tomcat won't start.

Comment: From your screenshot of Tomcat's log [1] Your environment variables look OK. [2] It does not seem that any attempt was made to start Tomcat. So can you add the screen shot of the Tomcat error (_"The system cannot find the specified file"_) to your question?

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can [start and stop Tomcat from the command line](https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-start-and-stop-apache-tomcat-from-the-comma/) rather than within NetBeans. Though not an ideal solution, that's much easier than reinstalling NetBeans repeatedly. And if that approach works it will confirm that there is nothing wrong with your Tomcat 8.5.93 installation.

Comment: You could also use **Services > Servers >Add Server...** to add another instance of Tomcat to NetBeans with a different version. For example, see if you can [download and use Tomcat 9.0.81](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi) within NetBeans instead of Tomcat 8.5.93.

Comment: I have tried Tomcat 9.0 and 11.0, and the result is still the same.Thank you for your response. I have now set my computer to never shut down, so I don't need to re-download it.

Comment: You might check whether any errors are being written to the NetBeans log file. To do that [1] Open the log in NetBeans using **View > IDE Log**. [2] Attempt to start Tomcat. [3] Update your question if any new messages are written to that log as a result of attempting to start Tomcat. You could also review the entire log to see if there are any unexpected errors or stack traces that might indicate a problem with the installation of NetBeans.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I configured NetBeans to go to "Tools -> Options -> General -> Proxy Settings: No Proxy." This way, my Tomcat won't be affected by shutdowns anymore.